# Is there a restriction in WP on the use of jQuery load function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm just trying to load a simple txt file for testing purposes.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#buttonAjax").click(function(){

        jQuery("#demo").load("demo.txt");
        alert('inside jquery');
    });
});
```

The code works because the alert works, but it doesn't load demo.txt (Hello Im demo text).

I tried one solution I found on SO and it doesn't work either:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#buttonAjax', function() {
        alert("inside ajax");
         jQuery("#demo").load("demo.txt");
    });
});
```

I am aware of wp_localize and WP ajax, I read the Codex, but I just want to make the load method work.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

PS. If it's a duplicate (not ajax, but showing to make load work) please post it in comments, don't just blindly downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use a full URI when specifying a location of a resource (in this case a file). With relative URIs like you use for you data file here, the URI will be appended to the URL in the address bar which will result in surprising URLs when you use permalinks.

In practice the pattern for developing such thing is to upload the files via the admin and use the URL you get via the attachment API. This way you do not need to assume anything about which part of the server are accessible to the user. 
If it is part of a theme, then you do know where it i located, just use the proper theme api to get the theme's root url.